# Azure databricks : pandas.read_parquet error

Tags: pandas, pyspark, azure-databricks, fsspec

I have some error to read parquet into pandas in databricks like in the following :

[image]

anyone has an idea ?following is my databricks runtime.

[image]

my pandas version

[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with pandas, but the protocol / path you gave. Try replacing `abfss` with `az` or `abfs`

Comment: ^ this is very probably it!

Comment: ....or maybe dbfs://

Comment: why not using `spark.read.parquet`? it’s much better than pandas